# Regex to split and ignore brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split by comma in the text but the text also has a comma inside brackets which need to be ignored

Input text : Selectroasted peanuts,**Sugars (sugar, fancymolasses)**,Hydrogenatedvegetable oil (cottonseed and rapeseed oil),Salt.

Expected output:

- Selectroasted peanuts
- Sugars (sugar, fancymolasses)
- Hydrogenatedvegetable oil (cottonseed and rapeseed oil)
- Salt

MyCode

```
string pattern = @"\s*(?:""[^""]*""|\([^)]*\)|[^, ]+)";
string input = "Selectroasted peanuts,Sugars (sugar, fancymolasses),Hydrogenatedvegetable oil (cottonseed and rapeseed oil),Salt."; 
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
{ 
Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Value); 
}
```

The output I am getting:

- Selectroasted
- peanuts
- Sugars
- (sugar, fancymolasses)
- Hydrogenatedvegetable
- oil
- (cottonseed and rapeseed oil)
- Salt

Please help.

Comment: What happens to the final `.` after `Salt`? Is it OK if you get `Salt.` in the output?

Comment: yes I can manage even if I get Salt. in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```cs
string pattern = @"(?:""[^""]*""|\([^()]*\)|[^,])+";
string input = "Selectroasted peanuts,Sugars (sugar, fancymolasses),Hydrogenatedvegetable oil (cottonseed and rapeseed oil),Salt."; 
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input.TrimEnd(new[] {'!', '?', '.', '…'}), pattern)) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", m.Value); 
}
// => Selectroasted peanuts
//    Sugars (sugar, fancymolasses)
//    Hydrogenatedvegetable oil (cottonseed and rapeseed oil)
//    Salt
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/NvhjoK). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CE9F6e/1), too. It matches one or more occurrences of

- `"[^"]*"` - `"`, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `\([^()]*\)` - a `(`, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `[^,]` - a char other than a `,`.

Note the `.TrimEnd(new[] {'!', '?', '.', '…'})` part in the code snippet is meant to remove the trailing sentence punctuation, but if you can affort `Salt.` in the output, you can remove that part.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I spent 4 hours and got all types of outputs except for what I wanted. Cheers!

Comment: I tried upvoting earlier but my it gave error as my reputation was less than 15, now I just upvoted the answer, thanks again.